# Slow Blazor WASM Initial Load in Mobile/PC

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created a blazor wasm which is 12mb in size.
I noticed it is taking 20 seconds to load it initially.

I tried the lazyloading approach and made my application 8mb upon loading,
However it still take long to initial load

Test Result

### PC Browser

Initial Load: 16seconds, Subsequent Load 9-12 seconds (FireFox)

Initial Load: 30+seconds, Subsequent Load 1-2seconds seconds (Edge)

Initial Load  30+seconds , Subsequent Load 1-2 seconds (Chrome)

### Mobile

Initial Load: 50seconds, Subsequent Load 9-12 seconds (FireFox)

Initial Load  24+seconds , Subsequent Load 11-12 seconds (Chrome)

Internet speed 25mbps download  fiber

Can someone help?

Comment: 12MB is pretty big. Can you confirm that you first published the app using a Release buidl configuration with IL trimming enabled before taking these measurements? See https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/ for details on publishing Blazor apps.